# EC2 Password expire dont have previous password

Tags: ubuntu, password

Our server guys setup a password expire policy but never set a password for the default user now the password has expired but I am unable to change it as it asks for the current password which we dont have.

Can anyone help me? I cant access my server.

Comment: Your server guys can help you.

Comment: It's strange to even be using passwords in EC2.  They do give you a hearty shove towards SSH keys.

Comment: Yes I do agree to you Ladadadada but we are getting a compliance certificate and this was their requirement. I Found an answer here 
http://superuser.com/questions/576932/turning-off-password-expiration-on-linux

the change needs to be made on /etc/shadow file

Answer (score 0):

I Have found a solution for my question

the file /etc/shadow must be edited and remove all parameters that is after the first 2

You can read more here
https://superuser.com/questions/576932/turning-off-password-expiration-on-linux